# Use Parameter From HTTP CALL ON SQL CALL (SAP B1if)

Tags: sapb1

I am working on creating a scenario triggered by an HTTP Call to display the result of an sql query in a web page , my need is to use a parameter from my HTTP Call like (CardCode). (It's work well without parameter)

**My scenario is very basic :**
[image: My Sceario img]

**My SQL Statement :** i don't know where to get my parameter
[image: My SQL Statement img]

**Inbound -> Channel :**
[image: My inbound img]

Can anyone please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CardCode can be a part of the HTTP body. You have to give the user a textbox on the website to fill in the cardcode. When the user press an button then you have to trigger/call your Scenario with the CardCode in the Body.
Then in your query you can refer like this:

```
/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role=&apos;S&apos;]/bfa:io/bfa:key[./@name=&apos;CardCode&apos;]
```

Comment: Thanks @AquaVitale for your answer, when i try to set my parameter with "/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role=&apos;S&apos;]/bfa:io/bfa:key[./@name=&apos;CardCode&apos;]" the result of my parameter is 'false', maybe i d'ont do it well

Comment: what i did is,  in my SQLCall Atom i create a variable 'VarTest' with the value --select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role=&apos;S&apos;]/bfa:io/bfa:key[./@name=&apos;VarTest&apos;]/@value" --

Comment: Thanks @AquaVitale for your feedback, i forgot to telle you that i had change the value of my SQLCall parameter, i put "/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role='S']/bfa:io/bfa:key[./@name='VarTest']/@value" without "&apos;" i dont know what is the diferrence but it works very well